# Django request.body test failure

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was running some django tests and ran into a problem where the POST data was missing. In order to trace the problem i printed `request.body` to see if the data got there, but when I print it, the problem goes away and the POST data is available.

If I put this code in my view the tests will pass:

```
 if request.body:
    print("*")
 ...
```

I'm using django 1.8.14 and django rest framework. Anyone have an idea of why this could be happening?

Comment: Can you provide rest of the code?

Comment: I'll see if I can make a minimal example that breaks. There is to much code to post.